# Xcode won't compile Exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode

I don't know what changed but my project will no longer compile. Ie spent days trying to figure out why. Ive tried many of the solutions presented on here but can't find a solution to the following error

```
CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
    cd "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto"
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc -incremental -module-name Pesto -Onone -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.1.sdk -target arm64-apple-ios9.0 -g -module-cache-path /Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -Xfrontend -serialize-debugging-options -enable-testing -I /Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-cyvdlxrvnewxebayvgydrrevckif/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F /Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-cyvdlxrvnewxebayvgydrrevckif/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks -c -j8 /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/MessagesCell.swift /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/PestoLoginViewController.swift /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/UserProfileViewController.swift /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/GroupsViewController.swift /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/Camera.swift /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/UsersFriendsTableViewController.swift /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/LocalMessagesViewController.swift /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/CheckInViewController.swift /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/Images.swift /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/SelectMultipleViewController.swift /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/AppDelegate.swift /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/PushNotification.swift /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/SearchViewController.swift /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/ChangePasswordViewController.swift /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/Utilities.swift /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/ParkBenchTimer.swift /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/MainViewController.swift /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/PestoSignUpViewController.swift /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/SelectSingleViewController.swift /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/FriendsChatViewController.swift /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/FriendCheckInTableViewCell.swift /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/FriendRequestsTableViewController.swift /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/Messages.swift /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/ProfileViewController.swift /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/ImageViewController.swift /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/File.swift /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/ChatViewController.swift /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/NSNotificationCenterKeys.swift /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/FriendsTableViewController.swift /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/Constants.swift -output-file-map /Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-cyvdlxrvnewxebayvgydrrevckif/Build/Intermediates/Pesto.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pesto.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Pesto-OutputFileMap.json -parseable-output -serialize-diagnostics -emit-dependencies -emit-module -emit-module-path /Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-cyvdlxrvnewxebayvgydrrevckif/Build/Intermediates/Pesto.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pesto.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Pesto.swiftmodule -Xcc -I/Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-cyvdlxrvnewxebayvgydrrevckif/Build/Intermediates/Pesto.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pesto.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-cyvdlxrvnewxebayvgydrrevckif/Build/Intermediates/Pesto.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pesto.build/Pesto-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-cyvdlxrvnewxebayvgydrrevckif/Build/Intermediates/Pesto.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pesto.build/Pesto-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-cyvdlxrvnewxebayvgydrrevckif/Build/Intermediates/Pesto.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pesto.build/Pesto-all-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-cyvdlxrvnewxebayvgydrrevckif/Build/Intermediates/Pesto.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pesto.build/Pesto-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-cyvdlxrvnewxebayvgydrrevckif/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -Xcc -I/Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pods/Headers/Public -Xcc -I/Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pods/Headers/Public/Bolts -Xcc -I/Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pods/Headers/Public/FBSDKCoreKit -Xcc -I/Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pods/Headers/Public/FBSDKLoginKit -Xcc -I/Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleMaps -Xcc -I/Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pods/Headers/Public/JSQMessagesViewController -Xcc -I/Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pods/Headers/Public/JSQSystemSoundPlayer -Xcc -I/Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pods/Headers/Public/Parse -Xcc -I/Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pods/Headers/Public/ParseFacebookUtilsV4 -Xcc -I/Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pods/Headers/Public/ParseUI -Xcc -I/Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-cyvdlxrvnewxebayvgydrrevckif/Build/Intermediates/Pesto.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pesto.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-cyvdlxrvnewxebayvgydrrevckif/Build/Intermediates/Pesto.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pesto.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -emit-objc-header -emit-objc-header-path /Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-cyvdlxrvnewxebayvgydrrevckif/Build/Intermediates/Pesto.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pesto.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Pesto-Swift.h -import-objc-header /Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/Pesto-Bridging-Header.h -Xcc -working-directory/Volumes/Mac\ OSX\ Backup/Dropbox/Pesto

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

when I compile from command line all it says is

```
CompileSwift normal arm64 /Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/CheckInViewController.swift
    cd /Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/MessagesCell.swift" "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/PestoLoginViewController.swift" "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/UserProfileViewController.swift" "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/GroupsViewController.swift" "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/Camera.swift" "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/UsersFriendsTableViewController.swift" "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/LocalMessagesViewController.swift" -primary-file "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/CheckInViewController.swift" "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/Images.swift" "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/SelectMultipleViewController.swift" "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/AppDelegate.swift" "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/PushNotification.swift" "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/SearchViewController.swift" "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/ChangePasswordViewController.swift" "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/Utilities.swift" "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/ParkBenchTimer.swift" "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/MainViewController.swift" "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/PestoSignUpViewController.swift" "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/SelectSingleViewController.swift" "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/FriendsChatViewController.swift" "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/FriendCheckInTableViewCell.swift" "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/FriendRequestsTableViewController.swift" "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/Messages.swift" "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/ProfileViewController.swift" "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/ImageViewController.swift" "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/File.swift" "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/ChatViewController.swift" "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/NSNotificationCenterKeys.swift" "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/FriendsTableViewController.swift" "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/Constants.swift" -target arm64-apple-ios9.0 -Xllvm -aarch64-use-tbi -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.1.sdk -I /Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-cyvdlxrvnewxebayvgydrrevckif/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F /Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-cyvdlxrvnewxebayvgydrrevckif/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks" -enable-testing -g -import-objc-header "/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pesto/Pesto-Bridging-Header.h" -module-cache-path /Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-cyvdlxrvnewxebayvgydrrevckif/Build/Intermediates/Pesto.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pesto.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-cyvdlxrvnewxebayvgydrrevckif/Build/Intermediates/Pesto.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pesto.build/Pesto-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-cyvdlxrvnewxebayvgydrrevckif/Build/Intermediates/Pesto.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pesto.build/Pesto-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-cyvdlxrvnewxebayvgydrrevckif/Build/Intermediates/Pesto.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pesto.build/Pesto-all-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-cyvdlxrvnewxebayvgydrrevckif/Build/Intermediates/Pesto.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pesto.build/Pesto-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-cyvdlxrvnewxebayvgydrrevckif/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -Xcc "-I/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pods/Headers/Public" -Xcc "-I/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pods/Headers/Public/Bolts" -Xcc "-I/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pods/Headers/Public/FBSDKCoreKit" -Xcc "-I/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pods/Headers/Public/FBSDKLoginKit" -Xcc "-I/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleMaps" -Xcc "-I/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pods/Headers/Public/JSQMessagesViewController" -Xcc "-I/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pods/Headers/Public/JSQSystemSoundPlayer" -Xcc "-I/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pods/Headers/Public/Parse" -Xcc "-I/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pods/Headers/Public/ParseFacebookUtilsV4" -Xcc "-I/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto/Pods/Headers/Public/ParseUI" -Xcc -I/Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-cyvdlxrvnewxebayvgydrrevckif/Build/Intermediates/Pesto.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pesto.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-cyvdlxrvnewxebayvgydrrevckif/Build/Intermediates/Pesto.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pesto.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc "-working-directory/Volumes/Mac OSX Backup/Dropbox/Pesto" -emit-module-doc-path /Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-cyvdlxrvnewxebayvgydrrevckif/Build/Intermediates/Pesto.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pesto.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CheckInViewController~partial.swiftdoc -Onone -module-name Pesto -emit-module-path /Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-cyvdlxrvnewxebayvgydrrevckif/Build/Intermediates/Pesto.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pesto.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CheckInViewController~partial.swiftmodule -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-cyvdlxrvnewxebayvgydrrevckif/Build/Intermediates/Pesto.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pesto.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CheckInViewController.dia -emit-dependencies-path /Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-cyvdlxrvnewxebayvgydrrevckif/Build/Intermediates/Pesto.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pesto.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CheckInViewController.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-cyvdlxrvnewxebayvgydrrevckif/Build/Intermediates/Pesto.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pesto.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CheckInViewController.swiftdeps -o /Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pesto-cyvdlxrvnewxebayvgydrrevckif/Build/Intermediates/Pesto.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pesto.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CheckInViewController.o

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(1 failure)
```

It also shows several warnings for this

```
2015-12-08 10:03:55.798 xcodebuild[18105:5225464]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDELanguageSupport/IDELanguageSupport-9046/XCLanguageSupport/XCSwiftCommandOutputParser.m:350
Details:  Encountered error handling message: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unable to convert data to string around character 73." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unable to convert data to string around character 73.}
Object:   <XCSwiftCommandOutputParser: 0x7fd63611a880>
Method:   -writeBytes:length:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fd632298370>{number = 13, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
```

Ive been trying just about everything including re-installing Xcode. I can't find any hint in either of these as to what the issue is.

I can't seem to find anything pointing to what source file it is trying to compile when it hits this.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have this in a code repo where you can go to prior version? I have my dev machine to do automatic backups as a fail safe. Having said that, Have you considered rebuilding your project file from scratch? I have had to do this twice before. Create new project with the same name and then manually add all the files from the old project. It's tedious but it might be an option to consider. You'll also want to copy over your info.plist file for the project and podfile (if u use Cocoapods).

Comment: Yeah I did rebuild by starting over and coping all my stuff back in, no luck. I do have an older version. Unfortunately I made a lot of chances in between :(

Comment: I have done this for some pretty ugly projects. It usually involves: 1) Create new project with same name. 2) Copy over all files while maintaining same project structure. 3) Copy project plist files. 4) If the project contained several schemes build them from scratch. 5) If project includes CocoaPods copy the podfile and run ‘pod install’.

Comment: Are you able to create a new test project and run it to determine your Xcode setup isn's screwed up? Also, download some existing sample code or retrieve an old copy of your code that was working and see if it will build. Again, what you are trying to do is validate that your Xcode system isn't messed up.

Comment: One of the other thoughts I had is if you might have a damaged resource in your project. You'd have to use some disk utility to check that. Another thought is to try XCTool which is provides verbose output that is much easier to read during build time to see if that flags anything: http://nshipster.com/xctool/

Comment: @xdeleon I'm going to give XCtool a try and see

Comment: Nothing worked. I ended up slowly rebuilding the project from scratch and copying over anything I felt was safe and recompiling after every step. Its finally good. Still have no clue what caused this error or how I could have diagnosed it. Good luck to all who face this and make sure you keep plenty of backups on hand.

Comment: That's kinda what I was recommending as a last measure. The upside for me is that I had to do this on projects where the other developer was gone and in the rebuild process I had to fix/change things in the new Project so I had a better idea of what all the settings were and why they were there. I'm guessing this worked the 2nd time because you were more meticulous about it? If this helped shoot an upvote over but if it didn't no worries. Cheers.